# Subdomain Routing in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, subdomain

Any ideas on how subdomain routing can be achieved with meteor?

Or would it be best to use a reverse proxy such as nginx or HAproxy?

i can use something like /?s=subdomain in nginx

But that seems like a hacky way to achieve what should be possible with the router

I ahve no idea what the caveats will be (being new to meteor)and whether it can be counted on in a produciton environment w/high traffic(the routing call I mean).

any idea how meteor achieve his on their server?

EDIT: specifically how to achieve http://subdomain.example.com routing to Collection.content.find({'domain':'subdomain'})

EDIT #2 : I have achieved this using nginx, solution to follow. but please see this question which answers most of my concerns and gives me a way to also achieve this with node : [nginx vs node-http-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309425/nginx-vs-node-http-proxy).

Comment: one can use Backbone package and use Backbone's router or use meteorite and this atmosphere package: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

Comment: Yes, I understand the routing concept, but I was specifically asking about the ability for meteor to affect the domain name e.g. http://subdomain.example.com routing to a query on a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to look into something like node-http-proxy to solve your problem. I had a similar routing problem (when bundled and deployed) and it solved mine!

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/

Comment: Actually this answer below answers most of my concerns, and they also just recently added regex support for domains too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309425/nginx-vs-node-http-proxy